# @channel Slack notification in Jenkins post-build action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

I am integrating a Slack bot in Jenkins post-build action. I have been able to send notification and create custom messages using the Slack plugin, however I wanted to send a `@channel` or `@bot` in the bot message which can be used to urgently notify the team.

Is there any existing way/hack to do this? Unfortunately, using these keywords via the plugin just result in them being rendered as plain text, without any broadcast action.

Comment: What happens if you simply include `@channel` in the message?

Comment: @halfer it just goes as plain text, it does not trigger any notification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To mention someone or a channel you can use one of the following syntax:

- `<!channel>`
- `<!group>`
- `<!here>`
- `<!everyone>`
- `<@USERID>`
- `<#CHANNELID>`

See [Basic message formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) for more information.